# I need a step counter in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, counter

I have read many links talking about pedometers and step counting and they involve services and advanced sensor readings.

In my app I only need to listen if the user has moved like 10 steps when a button is pushed and if so then do stuff. The idea is that the user is in a forest and if he walks some steps, a random tree can appear and user will have a chance to chop it by shaking the phone.

Is there any simple solution to start counting steps when a button is pushed and if needed number of steps is reached then stop counting them and perform an action?
Im new to android. I would appreciate any example code. Thanks.
Looking forward to something like this:

```
SearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //a code to start counting steps here

           if (steps > 9) {
            //a tree appears
            //stop counting steps
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int steps = 0;
SearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    //a code to start counting steps here
      steps = steps + 1; 

       if (steps > 9) {

        //a tree appears

        //stop counting steps

       steps = 0;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I dont need to add steps when a button is pushed. I need some pedometer or sensor to start reading step count when the user walks. So If the user has walked 10 steps in real life, the app can respond to it.